# Two dimensional array address

Tags: c

I have two structures as follows

```
typedef struct Rsp_s {
    u8    code;
    u8 Count;
}Rsp_t;

typedef struct Field_s {
     u8    State;
     u8    present;
     u8    previous;
     u8    event;
} Field_t
```

Then i have

```
Rsp_t *rsp;
Field_t data[3][7]
```

I want `data[0][0]` to follow `rsp->Count`. 
How do i do that?

```
data = (Field_t *)(&(rsp->Count) +1);
```

does not do it.

Comment: you've swapped the order, kind of. You'd also need to declare `a` as a pointer to an int pointer

Comment: `&b[0][0] = a` attempts to set the value of `&b[0][0]` to the value of `a`. But `&b[0][0]` cannot be modified since it's fixed. Thus the error you see.

Comment: actually I'm wrong, `a = &b[0][0];` is legal it seems, but you'd certainly won't be able to dereference it with `[][]`

Comment: @Ben Sure you can; you just need some casting, like this: `((int**)a)[0][0] = 1;` Not that it would likely be a useful thing to do, but this is C, you're allowed to shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a variable like this ...

```
int b[3][7];
```

... its memory location is assigned by the compiler if `static` or given memory from the stack if `auto`matic, and therefore cannot be changed programatically.  You can however access this memory, and read to and write from it, by using a pointer ...

```
int (*a)[7] = b;
```

The following are equivalent:

```
b[0][0] = b[1][1];
a[0][0] = a[1][1];
```

Comment: I think you should also add that the following is legal and works: `int* a = (int*)b[0];` gets you the 1-d pointer to the contiguous memory. I always use `int* a = &b[0][0]` cuz I like it better, but to each their own.

Comment: And to clarify, when he said the following are equivalent, another way to say it is `&pb[x][y]==&b[x][y]`

Comment: I've never seen this before: `int (*pb)[7]`. What exactly are you doing here?

Comment: @sherrellbc `int (*a)[7]` declares one variable, a pointer to a 2D array, `[n][7]` in size.  `int *a[7]` would declare 7 variables, each a pointer to a single `int` or 1D `int` array, `[n]` in size.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment is the wrong way round. You want to assign to `a` the address of `b[0][0]`, so:

```
a = &b[0][0];
```

Comment: @user3821434 I don't think you know what you want

Comment: @user3821434, what AntonH has done above is exactly that. Doing this does not *replace* the base of b by a, but rather *points* a to the base of b.